# Neo4j Performance - IN Operator Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j

If I had a million users and  if I search them using IN Operator with more than 1000 custom ids which are unique indexed.

For example,in movie database given by neo4j 
Let's say I need to get all movies where my list of actors ( > 1000) should acted in that movie and ordered by movie released date and distinct movie results.

Is that really good to have that operation on database and what are the time complexities if I execute that in single node instance and ha cluster.

Comment: what did you test ? did you profile the queries by matching for 100 or 1000 users and see the difference ?

Comment: I didn't test that.I have just started writing cypher queries.I am playing around the movie db.any theoretical answer how it can perform?

Answer (score 3):

This will give you a rough guide on the computational complexity involved in your calculation.

For each of your Actors Neo will look for all the Acted_In relationships going from that node. Lets assume that the average number of Acted_In relationships is 4 per Actor.

Therefore Neo will require 4 traversals per Actor.
Therefore for 1000 Actors that will be 4000 traversals.
Which for Neo is not a lot (they claim to do about 1 million a second, but of course this depends upon hardware)

Then, the Distinct aspect of the query is trivial for Neo as it knows which Nodes it has visited, so Neo would automatically have the unique list of Movie nodes, so this would be very quick.

If the Release date of the movie is indexed in Neo the ordering of the results would also be very quick.

So theoretically this query should run quickly (well under a second) and have minimal impact on the database

Comment: just a note, the index on the release date will change nothing as they are not used for ordering

Comment: Part of the question above states that the Movies are 'ordered by movie released date'...

Comment: Yes, I mean having an index will not have any performance impact for the order bt

Comment: Oh, maybe my understanding is lacking. I thought when the traversal query has finished and Neo has the Movie nodes that it uses the index on the Release Date field to help sort the nodes prior to returning. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes, this would be a nice improvement btw. Note also that ordering prevents streaming results as it has first to collect all the elements before ordering them.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this will change my thinking for my apps. Note: streaming when you require an ordered list seems pointless as you cant do anything with the stream until you have all of it. Also in the application you would not have the benefit of the index, so have to use bruit force to order. Makes sense to me to be done in Neo. Do you know how Neo actually does an Order By then?

Comment: if indexing won't have any impact main target is to get by movie released date ordered  and   what is more efficient query for this

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'd do, I would start traversing from the actor with the lowest degree, i.e. the highest selectivity of your dataset. Then find the movies he acted in and check those movies against the rest of the actors.

The second option might be more efficient implementation wise. (There is also another trick that can speed up that one even more, let me know via email when you have the dataset to test it on).

```
MATCH (n:Actor) WHERE n.id IN {ids}
WITH n, SIZE( (n)-[:ACTED_IN]->() ) as degree
ORDER BY degree ASC 
WITH collect(n) as actors WITH head(actors) as first, tail(actors) as rest, size(actors)-1 as number
// either
MATCH (n)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
WHERE size( (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]->() ) > number AND ALL(a in rest WHERE (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m))
RETURN m;

// or
MATCH (n)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
WHERE size( (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]->() ) > number
MATCH (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a)
WHERE a IN rest
WITH m,count(*) as c, number
WHERE c = number
RETURN m;
```

Comment: I understand only first part collecting actors .  questions I had 1)is size of relationships that node having is a metadata it will  take 1 db hit 2) why are we doing this size( (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]->() ) > number what does that statement do is it same as (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-().can u please walk me through last statements

Comment: Not sure if your question was answered. This answer is saying first order the actors by how many movies they have acted in, and started with the ones who have the least. So, `size( (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]->() )` gets the number of movies an actor `m` has acted in.